# Beta websites under Stack Exchange

Tags: support, beta-sites

I had joined the quite a lot of beta websites under Stack Exchange ([Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) to name a few).

Out of sheer curiosity, I would like to know and understand if the websites are categorized as beta based on the number of questions asked there? I couldn't help but notice most of them have an average of only a few thousand questions. Will they be pulled down if the activity remain considerably low?

Comment: The linked duplicate contains the current policy for beta sites, when they turn in to 'graduated' (non-beta) sites, etc. That should answer all your questions—let me know if there's anything not addressed in there.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much solved my doubts and helped me learn a few jargons too!